# Find the maximum length of characters in a field

Tags: text-processing, csv

Can you tell me how to find the maximum length of characters in a given field?

For instance, with this input file:

```
s.no,name
1,ATM
35,money
63,back
```

The maximum length in field 1 is 2. So, I want the output to be:

```
s.no,name
01,ATM
35,money
63,back
```

Here, we just add the zeros before number if it is <2.
Please help me.

Comment: `s.no` are 4 characters. Aren't your fields defined by commas? Are we supposed to skip the first line as a header? How do we know the max length? Should we first read the entire file and find the longest field?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to find the maximum length. Comma is your field separator, and you need to ignore the first line:

```
len=$(awk -F, 'BEGIN{mn=0;} NR>1{n=length($1);mn=mn>n?mn:n;}END{print mn}' test.txt)
```

Now we use printf to expand the first field:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print $0};NR>1{ printf("%0'"$len"'d,",$1); for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print($i); }' < test.txt
```

Note the single quotes end before `"$len"` to insert the field length and then they continue.

EDIT (thanks @dave_thompson_085 for a more elegant solution):

```
len=$(awk -F, 'BEGIN{mn=0} NR>1{n=length($1);mn=mn>n?mn:n;}END{print mn}' test.txt)
awk -F, -vOFS=, -vmn=$len 'NR>1{ $1=sprintf("%0*d",mn,$1)} 1' test.txt
```

where the last `1` means true and empty action means `{print}`.

Comment: To editor @terdon, on the less serious side: cats are not useless. They are fluffy and cute and help you incrementally update the command without the last argument being in the way :)

Comment: Happily agree to fluffy and cute, no arguments there :). What do you mean about incrementally updating? Also, whenever you disagree with an edit, feel free to [roll it back](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: The edit is fine. I'm just saying that when I create a oneliner with features that I'm less familiar with, I test smaller parts first and then build it part by part to see if it still works. Editing the last command from history is easier if you don't have to skip over a word every time.
I just forgot to put the cat back in his box when I was finished :)

Comment: Tsk, what would Schrodinger say? :)

Comment: @terdon You might also want to see [Undefined behavior killed my cat](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/undefined-behavior-killed-my-cat/)

Comment: @orion you can generally use `<file.txt command_foo | command_bar` rather than `cat file.txt | command_foo | command_bar` -- the `<` redirection doesn't *have* to go at the end of the command.

Comment: The `for(i...)print($i)` does the wrong thing if NF>2, so for the example data I would just use `print($2)`. If you do need to handle more, easiest to use awk's default rebuild; also I would use printf %* instead of the tricky quoting, and the default print action; combining these: `gawk -F, -vOFS=, -vmn=$len 'NR>1{$1=sprintf("%0*d",mn,$1}1' `

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 excellent solution. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a 0 if the first column is a single character, this will do:

```
sed -e 's/^.,/0&/' input.txt
```

In lines where the second character is a comma, it prepends a 0.

If the maximum length of your first column becomes 3 instead of 2, then you can do like this:

```
sed -e 's/^.,/00&/' -e 's/^..,/0&/' input.txt
```

Or, if you want to make this all dynamic, and pad as many zeros as necessary depending on the longest value in the first column, you could use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1; NR > 1 { data[NR] = $0; w1[NR] = length($1); if (length($1) > max) max = length($1) } END { for (i=2; i<= NR; ++i) { w = max - w1[i]; if (w > 0) printf "%0*d", w, 0; print data[i] } }' input.txt
```

The same thing but expanded to multiple lines for readability, with comments:

```
awk -F, '
NR == 1  # the first line is the header, just print it as it is
NR > 1 {
    data[NR] = $0        # save the line
    w1[NR] = length($1)  # save the width of 1st field
    if (length($1) > max) max = length($1)  # update max length
}
END {  # pass 2: now that we know max length, print the lines
    for (i = 2; i <= NR; ++i) {
        w = max - w1[i]  # calculate the zeros we need to prepend
        if (w > 0) printf "%0*d", w, 0  # print w zeros, if necessary
        print data[i]    # print the saved line
    }
}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Janos. its executed but it insert only one 0 (zero). if suppose 0012,ATM
3455,money
063,back.. like this.. we dont know exactly how many zero's to add. plz tel me

Comment: @suneelbabu.etl did you try the `awk` solution? That should work, dynamically detecting the max length.

Comment: i tried janos, but it is also output came like this only.. plz tel me

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if (length ($2)>max) max=length($2)} END {print max}' filename
```

The above command displays length of longest *name* column (i.e, $2=2nd column)