# awk: sort by first column then second; output unique 1st column once but all 2nd column

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, perl, sort

I have a two-column file that you can create as follows

```
cat > twocol << EOF
007 03
001 03
003 01
137 12
001 11
002 01
002 02
002 03
001 02
002 04
137 94
010 21
001 01
EOF
```

The resultant file, `twocol`, has only the rows of digits.

---

**Desired Result**

I want to perform some kind of command on `twocol` and get the following result. (I think seeing it is much better than trying to restate my somewhat-confusing question title - "sort by first column then second; output unique 1st column once but all 2nd column".)

```
001 01
    02
    03
    11
002 01
    02
    03
    04
003 01
007 03
010 21
137 12
    94
```

---

That's different from what a simple `sort` will give me, i.e. different from

```
001 01
001 02
001 03
001 11
002 01
002 02
002 03
002 04
003 01
007 03
010 21
137 12
137 94
```

---

**My Work**

The <strike>only solution I've come</strike> first solution I came up with (before I got a decent `awk` script going) - which matches the Desired Result above in bold, uses several instances of `awk`, a bunch of `bash`, and some help from [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118740/291375).

```bash
col_1_max_len=$(awk '
  BEGIN{maxl=0;}
  {curr=length($1);max1=max1>curr?max1:curr;}
  END{print max1}' \
 twocol);
len1=$col_1_max_len;
len2=$(awk '
  BEGIN{max2=0;}
  {curr=length($2);max2=max2>curr?max2:curr;}
  END{print max2}' \
 twocol);
current_col_1_val="nothing";

while read -r line; do {
  current_row="${line}";
  col_1_val=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "${current_row}");
  col_2_val=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "${current_row}");
  if [ ! "${col_1_val}" == "${current_col_1_val}" ]; then
    printf "%0"$len1"d %0"$len2"d\n"  "${col_1_val}"  "${col_2_val}";
  else
    printf "%"$len1"s %0"$len2"d\n"  " "  "${col_2_val}";
  fi;
}; done < <(sort twocol)
```

I feel like I should be able to use one pass with `awk`, something like the answers that follow: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548349/6505499) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450156/6505499) , [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242532/291375) , [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65541584/6505499) , ...

I can't seem to get it hammered together without what feel like extra, clunky, memory-eating arrays. The format is also giving me a problem - the numbers in the first and second columns can go to more digits, and it would be preferable for things to look nice.

**Can anyone show me how to get this result with some nice** `awk` **code - preferably that can be used pretty-easily in the terminal?** `Perl` **answers are welcome, too.**

---

Oh, my system

```
$ uname -a && bash --version | head -1 && awk --version | head -1
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 MY-MACHINE 3.2.0(0.340/5/3) 2021-03-29 08:42 x86_64 Cygwin
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.2.0-p9, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

(I get exactly the same behavior on my Fedora and Ubuntu machines.)

---

**Edit**

I came up with an `awk` solution. It looks all nice and short, but I still feel there are problems.

```bash
awk '{if (!vals[$1]++) print($0); else print("   ",$2);}' <(sort twocol)
```

I think I'm using a bunch of memory with the `vals` array - as of now, my file only has ~10k lines, but I hope to scale it up. I hard-coded in the format, but I don't like it because I could have strings of varying lengths.

I can fix that (the formatting) if I make three passes with `awk` and pass in variables.

```bash
length1=$(awk '
  BEGIN{maxl=0;}
  {curr=length($1);max1=max1>curr?max1:curr;}
  END{print max1}' \
 twocol);

length2=$(awk '
  BEGIN{max2=0;}
  {curr=length($2);max2=max2>curr?max2:curr;}
  END{print max2}' \
 twocol);

awk -vlen1=$length1 -vlen2=$length2 '
{
  if (!vals[$1]++) 
    printf("%0*d %0*d\n",len1,$1,len2,$2); 
  else 
    printf("%*s %0*d\n",len1," ",len2,$2);
}' <(sort twocol)
```

Result matches the Desired Result exactly (see the part in bold, above), but I hope there's a way to do it all with one pass of `awk`.

Can anyone share something that matches the characteristics I've mentioned? Any comments about the time performance and/or the memory performance of the different methods would also be appreciated.

I think it might also be possible to do the sorting in `awk`; I'd like to know, especially if it could be more efficient. **Edit:** It can be done, as @steeldriver and @markp-fuso show below.

Comment: I just re-read the full question and your `awk '{if (!vals[$1]++) print($0); else print("   ",$2);}' <(sort twocol)` works quite well :-); if you actually find yourself with memory issues you can easily replace the array reference with a 'previous' variable (eg, my 2nd `awk` script)

Comment: any attempt to sort the data within `awk` (eg, my 1st `awk` script, steeldriver's `awk` script) are going to require storing the file in memory; you can get away from the memory-usage question by using `sort` to feed a sorted stream to `awk`, and depending on your `sort` version there may be some options (memory size, # of cpus) to improve on `sort`'s performance

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about memory stuff, @markp-fuso, as well as for giving the great answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t"  }
      { a[$1][$2] }                               # we can sort on both indices to obtain the desired ordering
END   { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"    # applies to all follow-on array references (ie, both indices of the a[] array)
        for (i in a) {
            firstcol = i
            for (j in a[i]) {
                print firstcol, j
                firstcol = ""
            }
         }
      }
' twocol
```

**NOTE:** this requires `GNU awk 4.0+` for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` support

This generates:

```
001     01
        02
        03
        11
002     01
        02
        03
        04
003     01
007     03
010     21
137     12
        94
```

---

If `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` is not available we can use `sort` to feed a simplified `awk` script:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { if ($1 != prev1) {
           print $1,$2
           prev1 = $1
        }
        else
           print "",$2
      }
' < <(sort twocol)
```

This also generates:

```
001     01
        02
        03
        11
002     01
        02
        03
        04
003     01
007     03
010     21
137     12
        94
```

Comment: Ah yes use index for both fields - much nicer!

Comment: Apologies for the (now reverted) edit. You had already pointed out your first version was gawk-specific, and there is nothing gawk-specific in the second one. My bad!

Comment: In the second script, if you make it `{ if ($1 == prev1) { key = "" } else { key = $1; prev1 = $1 } print key, $2 }` then a) you remove the negative logic (`!=`) which turns the `else` into a double negative (it is NOT true that $1 is NOT equal to prev1), and b) you can avoid having 2 separate `print` statements so if you need to change the output in future you don't need to do so in 2 places. So, you avoid negative logic and avoid duplicate code, both of which are generally bad in software.

Answer (score 9):

*Original awk solution removed - a [better solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769327/65304) has been posted*

---

Pragmatically, you could pre-sort the input and just use (any) awk to format it:

```
sort twocol | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1 == last ? "" : $1, $2; last = $1}'
001     01
        02
        03
        11
002     01
        02
        03
        04
003     01
007     03
010     21
137     12
        94
```

This produces tab separated output - if you want spaces, pipe the result through `expand`.

---

Alternatively, you could use perl hash of anonymous arrays to aggregate the second column values, then sort and print:

```
perl -alne '
  push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1] 
  }{ 
  foreach $k (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %h) {
    @a = sort {$a <=> $b} @{ $h{$k} };
    print join "\n", map { ($_ == 0 ? $k : "") . "\t" . $a[$_] } 0..$#a;
  }
  ' twocol
001     01
        02
        03
        11
002     01
        02
        03
        04
003     01
007     03
010     21
137     12
        94
```

The `{$a <=> $b}` are perhaps not necessary since your zero padded data sort the same lexicographically as numerically.

---

Just for fun, with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.0.0/):

```
mlr -S --nidx --ofs tab put -q '
  @m[$1] = is_not_array(@m[$1]) ? [$2] : append(@m[$1],$2); 
  end { 
    @m = sort(apply(@m, func(k,v) { return {k: joinv(sort(v), "\n\t")}; }));
    emit @m, ""
  }
  ' twocol 
001     01
        02
        03
        11
002     01
        02
        03
        04
003     01
007     03
010     21
137     12
        94
```

Comment: I like how you do the sort, and how you just use tab as the `OFS`. I've got some new things about `awk` (like `PROCINFO` and the `@` stuff) to learn. Oh, and **this has been tested, and it works!**

Comment: @bballdave025 someone else may post a better solution - meanwhile I've added a perl version that may be preferable

Comment: @bballdave025 and indeed someone has - assigning the second field to the inner array's index instead of its value so both may be sorted the same way

Comment: fwiw, you can nest `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` options; in this case you could replace `n = asort(a[k], b, "@val_num_asc")` with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"`; the follow-on `for/print` loop would then be replaced with something like `pfx=k; for (j in a[k]) {print pfx,a[k][j]; pfx="" }`

Comment: @markp-fuso I removed my awk version - you may wish to edit yours to remove the reference

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h;  %h.append: .split(/ \s+ /);  END put .key => .value.sort.join("\n\t") for %h.sort;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h;  %h.append: .words;  END put .key => .value.sort.join("\n\t") for %h.sort;'  file
```

Here's an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, the code above is somewhat `awk`-like and uses Raku's (like Perl's) `-ne` non-autoprinting command-line flags.

- A hash `%h` is declared in a `BEGIN` block.
- The line is `.split` on one-or-more `\s` space characters. Alternatively (second answer), Raku's `.words` routine is used to split on whitespace. For both answers, resultant (two) elements are understood as a key-value pair, which is `append`ed to the hash.
- In the `END` block, the `%h` hash (`sort`ed on keys) is out`put` individually, with each `.key` followed by each `.value` that have been `sort.join("\n\t")`. The `\t` moves values that wrap to the next line into the second column.

Sample Input:

```
007 03
001 03
003 01
137 12
001 11
002 01
002 02
002 03
001 02
002 04
137 94
010 21
001 01
```

Sample Output:

```
001 01
    02
    03
    11
002 01
    02
    03
    04
003 01
007 03
010 21
137 12
    94
```

Note, sometimes it's instructive to look at Raku's defaults, so here's the answer without "column-izing" the output as above (i.e. simpler code below):

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h; %h.append: .words; END say .key => .value.sort for %h.sort;'  file
001 => (01 02 03 11)
002 => (01 02 03 04)
003 => (01)
007 => (03)
010 => (21)
137 => (12 94)
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Hash
https://raku.org

Comment: I really like this Perl(-like?) solution. Thanks.